# Generate random string of words

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I'm having difficulty creating a random string of words to be used in a typing speed test.

The String generator file I wrote is as follows:

```js
const WordGenerator = () => {
  const WordBank = [
    'difficulty',
    'never',
    'furniture',
    'thus',
    'transportation',
    'opportunity',
    'beautiful',
    'exactly',
    'standard',
    'kept',
    'baseball',
    'perfectly',
    'term',
    'egg',
    'must',
    'fix',
  ];
  let result = '';
  
  for (let i; i <= 200; i++) {
    result = result.concat(WordBank[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)], ' ');
  }
  
  return result;
};

console.log(WordGenerator());
```

For some reason when I console.log this, it returns an empty string. I was hoping to have a string of 200 random words from the word bank.

Any suggestions?

ps: I had to remove words from the word bank because stack overflow wasn't allowing me to have so much code, Im originally using 250 words in the wordBank.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? What do you mean by "when I console.log this"?

Comment: `Math.floor(Math.random() * 250)]` Why `250`? That should be [`WordBank.length`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4550514/542251)

Comment: Right *Im originally using 250 words in the wordBank.*. Well if you use less words you need to use a different value for the random generator

Comment: *because stack overflow wasn't allowing me to have so much code* That also doesn't make any sense. It should be possible to iterate this 200 times without causing a SO

Comment: @Liam I changed it to 16 but the issue remains...

Comment: I've replaced 250 with WordBank.length, the problem I am having is that words are not appended to the result string and returns an empty string when I call the function in a console.log

Comment: `result +=` instead of `result =`

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Usually, all current browsers contain pretty good debugging support for JS

Comment: @NakarukatoshiUzumaki string.concat essentially already does this

Comment: @Liam didn't see it, forget about that :y

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issues are:
1- in the for loop you didn't initialize the variable i to start from 0:

```js
 for (let i ▶️= 0 ◀️; i <= 200; i++)
```

2- when getting a random index why are you using (250), you need to use the array length:

```js
const WordGenerator = () => {
  const WordBank = [
    'difficulty',
    'never',
    'furniture',
    'thus',
    'transportation',
    'opportunity',
    'beautiful',
    'exactly',
    'standard',
    'kept',
    'baseball',
    'perfectly',
    'term',
    'egg',
    'must',
    'fix'
  ]

  let result = ''
  for (let i = 0; i <= 200; i++) {
    result = result.concat(WordBank[Math.floor(Math.random() *  WordBank.length)] +' ')
  }
  return result
}

console.log(WordGenerator());
```